# SQLite SELECT last 2 records by Stock Symbol

Tags: select, sqlite, group-by, limit

I have a SQLite3 table of stock prices (see example below). I want to define a SELECT statement that will retrieve the last 2 records by TimeStamp in descending order for each stock Symbol (group). The primary key for the table is Symbol+TimeStamp.

```
Symbol  TimeStamp   Close
ZXYZ    2/12/2016 16:00 17.81
ZXYZ    2/16/2016 16:00 18.83
ZXYZ    2/17/2016 16:00 19.38
ZXYZ    2/18/2016 16:00 19.55 <--
ZXYZ    2/19/2016 16:00 20.31 <--
ZAGG    2/12/2016 16:00 9.10
ZAGG    2/16/2016 16:00 9.70
ZAGG    2/17/2016 16:00 9.59
ZAGG    2/18/2016 16:00 9.62  <--
ZAGG    2/19/2016 16:00 10.01 <--
ZAYO    2/12/2016 16:00 21.89
ZAYO    2/16/2016 16:00 23.22
ZAYO    2/17/2016 16:00 23.63
ZAYO    2/18/2016 16:00 23.80 <--
ZAYO    2/19/2016 16:00 23.51 <--
```

When complete, the resulting table should look like this:

```
Symbol  TimeStamp   Close
ZXYZ    2/18/2016 16:00 19.549999
ZXYZ    2/19/2016 16:00 20.309999
ZAGG    2/18/2016 16:00 9.62
ZAGG    2/19/2016 16:00 10.01
ZAYO    2/18/2016 16:00 23.799999
ZAYO    2/19/2016 16:00 23.51
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work in SQLite:

```
select sp.*
from stockprices sp
where sp.timestamp in (select sp2.timestamp
                       from stockprices sp2
                       where sp2.symbol = sp.symbol
                       order by sp2.timestamp desc
                       limit 2
                      )
order by sp.symbol, sp.timestamp desc;
```